# Comparing dictionaries in Python lists

Tags: python, list, dictionary

I have two lists which contain dictionaries. Each dictionary has only one entry. I would like to check if a key in dictionary A (in list X) also exists in a dictionary in list Y. If this is the case, the key and the values belonging to it should be printed.

Example:

```
listA = [{key1: value1}, {key2: value2}]
listB = [{key1: value3}, {key4: value4}]
```

In this case the output should be:

```
key1: value1, value3
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You have list of sets not dictionaries.

Comment: Sorry, that was a mistake. Thanks for noticing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A very simple way to do it would be:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

l1 = [{'1':"one"} , {'2':"two"}]
l2 = [{'3':"three"} , {'1':"one_too"}]

def cmp(l1,l2):
    for i in l1:    
        for j in l2:
            for (key1,value1),(key2,value2)  in zip(i.iteritems(),j.iteritems()):
                if key1==key2:
                    print key1+": "+value1+", "+value2
                    break

cmp(l1,l2)
```

Comment: This does not work for me. Zipping the lists matches the first item of L1 to the first item of L2, etc. The only time I would get a match with your solution is when these two coincidentally match up (which is almost never the case). Do you have any other idea?